# Rails calling a action with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application were I want to introduce some jquery code.

I have button

```
<button type="button" id="savesettings" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

Now I want when I press this button

```
$("#savesettings").click(function(){

                        })
```

A controller action should be called. like this:

```
<%=url_for(:action => :first, :id => @xyz.id, :mail => @xyz.hash_for_url)%>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly write `link_to` instead of `button` as,

```
<%= link_to "Save Changes", url_for(:action => :first, :id => @xyz.id, :mail => @xyz.hash_for_url), remote:true, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
```

`remote:true` will serve you request as js

Comment: thanks, is it also possible to do it as a ajax call?

Comment: basically remote:true does `ajax request` and gives `response in js`. To handle js response you need to have `<action_name>.js` file in application views folder